# Treeview Expand/collapse not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have an asp treeview that expand/collapse work fine on local ...but it give me errors when i upload this on live site...

Errors are below

```
         WebForm_InitCallback is not defined


         NetworkError: 404 Not Found    ....WebResource.axd?d=gadbiR_oDm56cBQvDxSVvV9T1EihsEfUV2kQ8sK3P5QkJX-ZM7DhAvzOEz7psSfvIeyXpVrkX09ODUOtVSJvasrTp4M1&t=634621105430701734
```

Comment: can you share your code ? or explain more . please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that your live site can run thensame version of .net